# IntStream.range().filter.mapToObj().collect what exactly the means

Tags: java, list, dictionary

I am new to Java and stuck while reading these particular lines of code:

```
private static void checkPrice(final List<String> prices) {
    List<String> inputCountryCodes = IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
            .filter(index -> (index % 2 == 0))
            .mapToObj(prices::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<String> distinctInputCountryCodes = inputCountryCodes.stream()
            .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Can anyone please explain the para1 and para2 of the code above what these particular lines of code do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IntStream.range(0, prices.size())
```

Its generating a integer stream from 0 to size(excluding) of prize List.
So lets say your `prices.size()` equals 3 then [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) will emmit 0, 1, 2

```
filter(index -> (index % 2 == 0))
```

Its intermediate operation will then [filter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#filter-java.util.function.IntPredicate-) those numbers produced by `InputStream`
basis on that number will be moded with 2. i.e to check if the number is even.
If it even it will be passed further or else thrown out

```
mapToObj(prices::get)
```

[mapToObj](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj-java.util.function.IntFunction-) It's taking that filtered number (even number) and use it to get String type object from `prices`.
So above code is like

```
mapToObj(num -> {
    String item = prices.get(num);
    return item;
})

collect(Collectors.toList());
```

collect the result from `mapToObj` into `List<String>`

So Your `List<String> inputCountryCodes` will contain item from `prices` whose index is even number.

```
inputCountryCodes.stream().distinct()
```

This will create a [Stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) out of your `inputCountryCodes` which is of type `List<String>`
then only take out [distinct](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--) items from it.
Example if your `inputCountryCodes` has `item1`, `item2`, `item2`, `item1`
it will result into `item1`,`item2`

```
collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Then [collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) result from distinct to `List<String>`

So finally your `List<String> distinctInputCountryCodes` will contains items from `prices`

```
a) whose index is an even number

b) And items are distinct
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through this one by one :

```
List<String> inputCountryCodes = IntStream.range(0, prices.size()).filter(index -> (index % 2 == 0))
            .mapToObj(prices::get)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- `IntStream` is Java interface for stream specifically for int type (for stream, google stream or Java.util.stream
- `range(0, prices.size)` is `static IntStream range(int startInclusive,   int endExclusive)`

  - ^ Creates an intstream from 0, `prices.size() - 1`
- `prices.size()` is length of prices
- `filter` is same in english as is in Java. It returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate (removes all those that don't match)
- `index -> index % 2 == 0`  is lambda fn that checks whether elements are divisable by 2 or not (%2 == 0 is the check)
- `mapToObj` eturns an object-valued **Stream** consisting of the results of applying the given function.
- `collect` is a mutable reduce function
- `Collectors.toList()` is class extending Object and `toList` is one of functions.

That's para 1

```
 List<String> distinctInputCountryCodes = inputCountryCodes.stream().distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- `inputCountryCodes` the string list obtained above
- `stream()` turns list into a stream
- `distinct` is name sake it gives distinct elements in a stream.
- `collect(Collectors.toList())` Already explained

Hope that explains it

Answer (score 0):

The first one is something like the following:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
for(int i = 0; i < prices.size(); i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0)
        result.add(prices.get(i));
```

The second one iterates through the list and removes the duplicates by boxing the `int` to `Integer` and using a `LinkedHashSet` object under the hood.

**Interpretation**

You can think `range(int a, int b)` as a `create a for loop beginning from a to b`

`filter(Predicate predicate)` applies the given predicate on the stream and filtering accordingly. This is similar to `if(condition) -> the iteration shall pass`

`collect(Collectors.toList())`collects the iterations, which made it this far in a list object.

`distinct()`removes the duplicates by first boxing the primitives, passing the objects to a set object and returning the distinct result.